# python inner classes how to create

Tags: python, class, inner-classes

I am trying to create a class called My_Axes. It has a module 'size' which takes as arguments the size of the figure, nx, ny - how many plots, and share - (True or False) whether I want to share the Xaxis or not.

Then there is a inner class called: 'Style'. It is intended to alter the look of the axes returned by My_Axes.size(). In this case I am aiming to a matlab like look thin axes and Helvetica font. Below is my code. Please forgive me as I am still learning python.

```
class My_Axes:

       def __init__(self):

              self.style = self.Style()

       def size(self,fig_siz,nx,ny,share):
              import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
              from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator 
              import numpy as np 


              self.fig_siz=fig_siz
              self.nx = nx
              self.ny = ny
              self.share = share


              fig = plt.figure(figsize = self.fig_siz)
              x, y = self.fig_siz


              self.nax = {}
              self.n = 0
              for i in range(self.nx):
                     for j in range(self.ny):
                            if self.share:
                                   width = (0.9/self.nx)
                                   height =(0.9/self.ny)
                                   xpos = 0.08 + i*width
                                   ypos = 0.08 + j*height
                                   a = fig.add_axes([xpos,ypos,width,height])
                                   self.nax['ax'+str(self.n)] = a


                                   if j > 0: self.nax['ax'+str(self.n)].set_xticklabels([])
                                   if i > 0: self.nax['ax'+str(self.n)].set_yticklabels([])
                                   self.nax['ax'+str(self.n)].yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='lower'))
                                   self.nax['ax'+str(self.n)].xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='lower'))
                                   self.n += 1
                            else:
                                   width = ((0.6+(x+y)/180.)/self.nx)
                                   height =((0.6+(x+y)/180.)/self.ny)
                                   xpos = 0.08 + (width  + 0.1)*i
                                   ypos = 0.08 + (height + 0.1)*j
                                   a = fig.add_axes([xpos,ypos,width,height])
                                   self.nax['ax'+str(self.n)] = a
                                   self.n += 1

                            axx = self.nax       
              return axx

       class Style:

              def __init__(self,axx):
                     self.nax = axx

              def matlb(self):

                     from matplotlib import rc, font_manager


                     ticks_font = font_manager.FontProperties(family='Helvetica', style='normal',
                     size=12, weight='normal', stretch='normal')
                     for a in sorted(self.nax):
                            aax = self.nax[a].xaxis
                            aay = self.nax[a].yaxis

                     for axis in ['bottom','left']:
                            self.nax[a].spines[axis].set_linewidth(0.3)

                     for axis in ['right','top']:
                            self.nax[a].spines[axis].set_visible(False)
                     aax.set_ticks_position('bottom')
                     aay.set_ticks_position('left')

                     lsiz = 8 + 4./self.n
                     self.nax[a].xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=lsiz)
                     self.nax[a].yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=lsiz)
                     return self.nax

#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@


aax = My_Axes().size((8,8),3,3,True)


aax.style.matlb
```

When I run the code, I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aya/Desktop/test_class2.py", line 103, in <module>
    aax = My_Axes().size((8,8),3,3,True)
  File "/Users/aya/Desktop/test_class2.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.style = self.Style()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/aya/Desktop/test_class2.py"]
[dir: /Users/aya/Desktop]
[path: /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin]
```

Comment: You should take a look to the Python coding guide a.k.a. The [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?). Your code is a little hard to read.

Comment: @Laurent LAPORTE I am sorry about that, but  thank you for your suggestion and attaching that link.

Comment: Note, `size` is a function, a method, not a module. Also, why do you want to use an inner class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exception is happening because the `Style` class doesn't have a constructor that takes zero non-`self` parameters, which is what it's looking for when you call `aax = My_Axes()...` at the bottom of the code.

The problem occurs on the line where you call `self.style = self.Style()`.

If you do want to create the `Style` object there, you need to edit the `My_Axes` constructor, so that it passes a valid `axx` parameter to a `self.Style(axx)` call, e.g.:

```
class My_Axes:

       def __init__(self, fig_siz,nx,ny,share):
              axx = self.size(fig_siz,nx,ny,share)
              self.style = self.Style(axx)

       # ...

       class Style:
              def __init__(self, axx):
                     # ...
#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

aax = My_Axes((8,8),3,3,True)

aax.style.matlb()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know how do I pass the axx to self.Style() when it is created under class My_Axes?

Comment: @user3578925 I added some example code, hopefully that answers your question

Comment: It's probably breaking on `aax.set_ticks_position('bottom')` because `aax` doesn't get defined before that line happens. I'm guessing it's because `for a in sorted(self.nax):` doesn't iterate on anything.

Comment: Really, you probably want to indent everything between and including `for axis in ['bottom','left']:` and `self.nax[a].yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=lsiz)` an additional time so that they are inside the `for a in sorted(self.nax):` block.

Comment: @Razihm I am now trying to use the second option you have suggested but now I am getting the error:  `aax.style.matlab
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'style'`. Your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: @user3578925 Your code was taking the output of `style()` (which is a dictionary) and assigning it to `aax`, and then treating it later like it was a `My_Axes` object. I  edited my answer to address that, as well as change how `axx` gets created. Also, since `matlb` is a method, you need to put parenthesis after it if you want to call it.

Comment: @Razihm I edit my code as per your suggestion above. Now I am getting:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aya/Desktop/test_class2.py", line 103, in <module>
    ax = My_Axes((8,8),3,3,True)
  File "/Users/aya/Desktop/test_class2.py", line 22, in __init__
    axx = self.size(fig_siz,nx,ny,share)
  File "/Users/aya/Desktop/test_class2.py", line 68, in size
    return axx     
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'axx' referenced before assignment
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]`

Comment: That means you never assign to `axx` before you hit `return axx` in `size(...)`

Comment: Thank you so much. You were write. axx wasn't referenced as I have indented the return statement for some reason. I am accepting your answer as the correct one.